# Blank Screen on windows

Tags: c#

I saw a question with regard to Linux on blanking the screen if the noise on a microphone went too high over a length of time.
The questioner wanted to use it so kids keep quiet while playing games.
[Linux Blank Screen](https://superuser.com/questions/545329/blank-screen-if-kids-yell-too-much)

How would the same task be completed using C# on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to turn off your screen:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //to DllImport

public int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
public int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170; //Using the system pre-defined MSDN constants that can be used by the SendMessage() function .


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
//To call a DLL function from C#, you must provide this declaration .


private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

SendMessage( this.Handle.ToInt32() , WM_SYSCOMMAND , SC_MONITORPOWER ,2 );//DLL function
}
```